# Jmeter: 443 failed to respond

Tags: https, jmeter

I'm a newbie to JMeter so be gentle. I have a simple test plan that hits a login page. At this point, it doesn't even log in, just loads the page. The problem is that on each run, the request for one of the CSS files on the page results in:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: example.com:443 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:286)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.receiveResponseHeader(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:212)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:697)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:455)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:2034)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:2002)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I run the test again, all other requests succeed, but this one file fails every time.

Here's the request data:

```
GET https://example.com/mysite/style/bootstrap.min.css
GET data:
Cookie Data:
JSESSIONID=0753E35583DE3C882E88BE4C37FCFB47; BIGipServerdemo-tomcat=654354624.51526.0000
Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: example.com
```

When I load this page in Chrome or Firefox, all files load, including this CSS file, without any problem. How can I fix this NoHttpResponseException so this CSS file (and I'm assuming more down the road) return as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file might be in your [browser cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), try using [clean session](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic) and inspect the request using browser developer tools and double check if the file still there. If not - it's an issue with your application deployment. If yes - I can think only of comparing requests sent by JMeter and real browser using either [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and browser developer tools or external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

As a workaround you can disable checking missing embedded resources by adding the next line to [`user.properties`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) file

```
    httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue with both embedded resources and the main HTTP requests.
Disabling the 'Use KeepAlive' option in the HTTP Request Samplers fixed the issue for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should check [HTTP_Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)'s `Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML Files` checkbox

> Tell JMeter to parse the HTML file and send HTTP/HTTPS requests for all images, Java applets, JavaScript files, CSSs, etc. referenced in the file

So you don't need to make explicit request for each CSS (As browser)